# Trying to writing a "ls" script on windows using win32api module of python

Tags: python-3.x, winapi

I m trying to create a ls script on Windows using python. I installed the win32api module but I really Don't know to use it. For instance I d like to add an option -l to see the size of the files and an option -c to count the number of files in a folder. 
Here is my code for the moment

```
import os 
import argparse
import win32api

def parse_args():
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Affiche les fichiers contenus dans un dossier')
parser.add_argument('directory', type=str, nargs='?', default='.')
parser.add_argument('--all','-a', action='store_true', help= "Inclus les fichiers cachés")
parser.add_argument('--recursive','-R', action='store_true', help=" Recherche recursive descend dans les dossiers")
parser.add_argument('--lenght','-l', action='store_true', help= "Affiche la taille des fichiers")
parser.add_argument('--count','-c', action='store_true', help=" Indique le nombre de lignes des fichiers")
parser.add_argument('--directories','-d', action='store_true', help=" N'affiche que les dossiers et le nombre de fichiers contenus")
parser.add_argument('--reverse','-r', action='store_true', help="Inverse l'ordre d'affichage")
return parser.parse_args()

def ls(args):

    if args.all:
            print ("afficher tous les dossiers et fichers cachés")
            ls_all(args)

    if args.recursive:
            print ("Recherche recursive descend dans les dossiers")
            ls_recursive(args)

    if args.lenght:
            print ("affiche la taille des fichiers")
            ls_long(args)

    if args.count:
            print ("indique le nombre de lignes des fichiers")
            ls_count(args)

    if args.directories:
            print ("N'affiche que les dossiers et le nombre de fichiers contenus")
            ls_directories(args)

    if args.reverse:
            print ("Inverse l'ordre d'affichage")
            ls_reverse(args)

    else:
        for fn in listdir(args):
                print (fn) 

def ls_all(args):
        attribute = win32api.GetFileAttributes(args.directory)


# def ls_long(args):


def listdir(args):
        dirs = os.listdir(args.directory)
        dirs.sort()
        return dirs

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parse_args()
    ls(args)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to use `ls` directly?

Comment: Mmm in fact it's for a personal project I have to do ;-)

Comment: OK. What exactly is your question? It looks like you just want us to write all the code for you. Because if you did some research you'd find loads of example code around. As it stands you appear to have made no effort to write any code beyond the args parse.

Comment: Sorry David I finally finished the code . My last comment was blocked but I find it hard as I am a new user of Stackoverflow...

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use the `os.path.getsize()` to get the size of the file, then count all the files under the directory:

   ```py
   for root, dirs, files in os.walk(args.directory):
       for f in files:
           size += os.path.getsize(os.path.join(root, f))

   print size
   ```
2. For number of files:

   ```py
   print len([name for name in os.listdir(args.directory) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(args.directory, name))])
   ```